# Avoid NetworkErrors when reloading page during fetch

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a small script that polls an API every 2 seconds for new data (has to be polling, as the API provider doesn't support webhooks, unfortunately). While it technically works, one thing that's been continously annoying me is that every time I reload the page, I get this error:

[image: NetworkError]

I'm pretty confident that this happens because during a refresh, the fetch request isn't completed.

```
function pollingLoop() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    fetch("http://some.url")
        .then(response => doStuffWithResponse(response))
        .catch(ex => console.error(ex))
        .finally(() => pollingLoop());
  }, 2000);
}
```

I could just remove the catch, but obviously that's just hiding the problem, not actually fixing it.

Any idea how I can get rid of this error properly?

Comment: Reloading the page is simply canceling any running background requests you might still have, but how is this actually a problem? Let it occur then, who cares?

Comment: Just because it's not a big problem doesn't mean it shouldn't be fixed. I want to learn how to do this stuff the right way.

Comment: But "doing stuff the right way" includes learning to realize what is a minor issue that does not warrant bothering with in the first place :-) And I am not sure if you actually realistically _can_ do anything about this here in that situation. Properly detecting a reload is not an easy thing to do, and neither is canceling a running fetch request.

Comment: I'm with @CBroe here. Why bother about an error that is caused by an intentional "poke"? There's nothing to fix here - just stop interrupting the ongoing `fetch` request on purpose. It's like `Ctrl + C`'ing a running Shell script and trying to avoid stopping it - that's just how it works and trying to change it will cause a headache while bringing probably close-to-zero rewards. The "right" thing to do here is to handle this error by simply printing a message to a console, like "Fetch request interrupted, will try again in 2 seconds" and that's all.